# asp.net crosspage postback on click doesn't run

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to get a crosspage postback to work in asp.net 2.0 the issue I seem to be having is the button that I press is meant to use it's on click event to store some session variables based on the values of other controls. This button has crosspage postback property to the relevant page.

The on click event seems to not run at all, it just seems to perform the postback to the other page straight away.

Is this standard behavior? Any work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found my answer

http://community.sgdotnet.org/blogs/chuawenching/archive/2007/03/08/ASP.NET-2.0-DataGrid_2F00_GridView-CrossPage-PostBack-.aspx

Seems like the transfer will be instant, no onClick event will run. The alternative is to use Server.Transfer in the onClick event.

Any other comments appreciated.